# include php file only once in project

Tags: php, file

I have a file (config.php) which has my app configuration data:

```
<?php

return [
    // here is my associative configuration array
    // having also Closures in it
];
```

What I do is sending this file to my Config class which will manipulate my data and it'll be my interface for configuration info.

```
Config::init(require('config.php'));
```

It that way, I don't want to can acces configuration info in any other way than using public Config class methods.

So, I need to can include config.php only once in my project (when is sent to Config class).

A solution would be with defining a constant in the top of file:

```
<?php

define('config', true);

return [
    // here is my associative configuration array
    // having also Closures in it
];
```

In that way, including config.php twice will generate error because 'config' constant get defined twice, which is illegal in php.

BUT, 'config' constant can easily be removed before second include. With:

```
runkit_constant_remove('config');
```

That's why I need to ask you for a more safe/trusty solution which can guarantee that configuration info can be taken only from Config class.

Comment: try require_once

Comment: _BUT, 'config' constant can easily be removed before second include_ What? How?

Comment: Yes. Can be removed anytime with runkit_constant_remove().

Comment: runkit_constant_remove is a PECL thing, its not native https://3v4l.org/RO3iV

Comment: You say a define() can't be removed later?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it with an ini file. Simple example below:

config.ini

```
[app]
user = myuser
pass = 123123
stage = 1
```

your config init:

```
Config::init(parse_ini_file('app.ini'));
```

parse_ini_file docu click [here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: This parse_ini_file() can also be used again, in app, later.

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu If that is a problem, then you can't guarantee anything. What is your actual concern? That you have untrustworthy programmers ignoring the config values?

Comment: Yes. That's my concern.

Comment: Well, you can't guarantee anything then. If they can write source code in the same namespace, they can do anything they want. For example, they could simply avoid using your Config class and hard-code whatever values they desire. If you want to segregate them, you need to build an API.

Comment: How to create an API. What do you mean?